# Clean way to set up an array of form elements in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to Javascript/React. I've adapted the code in https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html to set up an array of labels with a single `handleInputChange` handler.

It works, but it's a bit ugly as I've had to set the label names to be "0", "1", etc.. Is there a cleaner way?

```
class Reservation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputs: Array(10).fill("-"),
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const inputs = this.state.inputs.slice();

    const target = event.target;
    inputs[parseInt(target.name)] = target.value;
    this.setState({inputs: inputs});
  }

  render() {
    var labels = [...Array(10).keys()].map((i) => {
      const iAsString = i.toString();
      return <div><label>
          <input
            name={iAsString}
            value={this.state.inputs[i]}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </label></div>
      ;
    });

    return (
      <form>
        {labels}
        <p>{this.state.inputs.join(' | ')}</p> 
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edited** to make the issue clearer.

Comment: You could use `.map()`

Comment: @HåkenLid That still leaves you with label names like "0"?

Comment: Do you know the strings that you want to use for the labels? Why not define an array of input names and map that to your state and your view?

Comment: @sliptype they will be something like input0, input1, input2, ..., input9. I didn't follow the rest of your suggestion... what should I replace `parseInt(target.name)` with? I could take a substring, I guess, but it's messy...

Comment: Oh I see. You could use a `reduce` to turn the array of names into an object mapping names to values for your state. Then you can do the lookup like `inputs[target.name]` in `handleInputChange`